# Obtener nombre de tabla a partir de un atributo(s)

Tags: mysql, nodejs

Me gustaría saber si es posible obtener el nombre de una tabla a través de una consulta o de otra forma a partir de un atributo de esa tabla en concreto.

Ejemplo:

```
Tabla A:
Lugar    Nombre    Apellido
1        Pepito    Perez
1        Lucas     Rodriguez

Tabla B:
Lugar     Nombre    Apellido
2         Fernando  Flores
2         Daniela   Lopez
```

A mi me llega el lugar a través de un programa, y necesito implementar los datos que me llegan des de esa aplicación externa en la base de datos. Como he puesto, cada tabla tiene un lugar, y ese lugar es único en toda la tabla.

Es posible a través de ese atributo conseguir el nombre de la tabla para así poder insertar los valores?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Hola! Si tus tablas siguen todas la misma estructura, no es mas adecuado unir todas tus tablas en una sola? Así podrías trabajar mucho mejor. No se si tienes la posibilidad de hacerlo... Un saludo.

Comment: Hola! Pues la verdad es que no, son muchas tablas (+100) y cada una representa una tienda. También hay algunas de estas tablas que no siguen la misma estructura. Un saludo!

Comment: mas alla de que tener una tabla por tienda suena a muy mala idea (porque algo asi?? si es porque son de sistemas distintos, deberian ser base de datos distintas, no tablas distintas), cual es el problema al concatenar el nombre de la tabla en el from de la consulta?

Comment: Acabo de comprobar una cosa, y es que me habían explicado mal el sistema y esta separado por bases de datos distintas. Que he de hacer? Eliminar la pregunta o indicar que esta mal formulada la pregunta?